# Session scope spring statemachine

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-statemachine

I am developing a big eCommerce application, and i think this project may be a perfect fit for the checkout process. i just read the documentation but still have some little questions...

1- Can i have StateMachine created and injected in session scope? i think theoretically this can be done, but is it ok to have a stateMachine instance per session or is this overkill?

2- Can I persist the state to the session? How nice StateMachine plays with SpringSession? can the state persisted or serialized to Redis?

What is best practices to effectively use spring statemachine in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have to say no to your questions. Session scope, possibly yes, in theory, but because I haven't tried, answer is only yes in theoretical level. But having said that these are a *very* good questions indeed.

We're getting into `1.0.0.RELEASE` next week and after that we open project for new features and these are actually something I've played in my head what comes for the roadmap. I created issues [gh-110](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/110), [gh-111](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/111) and [gh-112](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/112) to track these.

Main focus for `Spring Statemachine 1.1.x` will be around `Spring Security` and we can throw in some love for `Spring Session` and `Scopes` as much as we can. All these are actually highly related to each others.

While this may not help you in any means right now, feel free to create new github tickets for stuff you need/want. Project is highly driven by stuff users are requesting. So this is a good moment to raise your voice and speak up!